# Cannot start quorum 7nodes example locally on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, istanbul, genesis, raft, quorum

I was trying to build 7nodes example on my pc locally ,following the process on quorum site (http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/7Nodes-Setup/) . but when I run "./raft-init.sh" (even with sudo) the following error appears:

```
[*] Cleaning up temporary data directories
[*] Configuring node 1 (permissioned)
INFO [08-31|21:49:29.528] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
WARN [08-31|21:49:29.529] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=4096 updated=1978
Fatal: Failed to read genesis file: open genesis.json: permission denied
```

I have no idea what to do?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The script expects to find the `genesis.json` file in the current directory.
Make sure you are in the correct directory (`examples/7nodes`). If the genesis.json file is not there then you must have had a problem with checking out the 7nodes example from github, or it must have been accidentally deleted.

BTW don't run as root, or using `sudo` else you'll most likely hit various issues.

Comment: yes , I have checked the 'genesis.json" already exist in  /7nodes directory.. 
so I don't know where's the problem!

Comment: Ah, just noticed that the error is "permission denied", so the problem is that you don't have read access to the genesis.json file.
Change the permissions and that should fix it.

Comment: More important perhaps, is why this permissions issue has occurred. Did you checkout from git as root (or using sudo)? If so then you may get further permission issues.
Make sure you have ownership and access to all files & directories under 7nodes.